# how to pass a string value into a gridview in C sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

hey i have  a query.... i have extracted data from database..currently that information is in a string variable...my point is to pass that string value into a gridview in the application..i have already created the gridview with checkbox list fitted into it...on inserting the values will the gridview will expand dynamically ??..if no then what to do ? how to push the data into gridview so that it expands dynamically? ..pls help me out

Comment: Why don't you try it, and tell us if it's not doing what you expected?

Comment: @user457272, ASP GridViews don't "expand dynamically".

Comment: -1 The absolute best learning method in this case (IMHO) is trial and error.  Your class or career (whichever the case may be) will be extremely difficult if you have to come here (or even to another forum) everytime you have a question that can simply be tried.  You are even listing the problem solving steps in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have your data in a datatable and bind the gridview to that datatable.  Take a look at this [sample](http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-Bind-GridView-to-DataTable.aspx) for some guidance.  If you have one long string what is the behavior that your expecting.